# Waiting on a service that itself relies on nested promises/observables

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to use the [Ionic Native QR Scanner](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/qr-scanner/) in an application. As I will need the scanner in multiple modules, I thought it would be a good idea to build a simple service that can open the scanner and return the result.

To start with, I'm using the sample code available on the link above:

```
// inside qrScannerService...
public scanQR(): Promise<void> {
    return this.qrScanner.prepare()
        .then((status: QRScannerStatus) => {
            if (status.authorized) {
                let scanSub = this.qrScanner.scan().subscribe((qrResult: string) => {

                    this.qrScanner.hide();
                    scanSub.unsubscribe();
                    // this is what I want, ultimately.
                    return qrResult; 
                });
                this.qrScanner.show();
            } else if (status.denied) {
                console.log("denied");
            } else {
                // permission was denied, but not permanently.
            }
        })
        .catch((e: any) => console.log('Error is', e));
}
```

So that's the service. In my module, I use the scanner service like so:

```
private doQRScan() {
    this.qrScannerService.scanQR().then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    });      
}
```

So I have a promise chain `doQRScan()`->`scanQR()`->`prepare()`->`scan()` and I need to wait on *all three* promises/observables, or I need to restructure the service method, but I'm fairly new to Angular and so far the answer eludes me.

As it stands, `prepare()` returns its promise and `doQRScan()` is satisfied, so the actual QR scan is never returned.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to return a new promise in your scanQR function . I haven't tested it, but something like this should work for you:

```
public scanQR() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.qrScanner.prepare()
        .then((status: QRScannerStatus) => {
            if (status.authorized) {
                let scanSub = this.qrScanner.scan().subscribe((qrResult: string) => {

                    this.qrScanner.hide();
                    scanSub.unsubscribe();
                    // this is what I want, ultimately.
                    // return qrResult;
                    resolve(qrResult) //-------> resolving your top level promise
                });
                this.qrScanner.show();
            } else if (status.denied) {
                console.log("denied");
                reject("denied!")
            } else {
                // permission was denied, but not permanently.
                reject("denied!")
            }
        })
        .catch((e: any) =>
            console.log('Error is', e)
            reject(e)
        );
})
```

}